# Converting a real into an integer in lisp

Tags: lisp, type-conversion

How can I convert a real number to an integer in LISP?

Is there any primitive function?

Example:

3.0 => 3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are multiple ways.

I will be using `f` instead of a float number below.

If you're interested in the next-highest integer, `(ceiling f)` gives you that. If you are interested in the next-lowest integer, `(floor f)` gives you that (for values like `1.0`, the two functions will return the same integer value). If you prefer having the closest integer, you can use `(round f)` to find it.

Those are the three simplest and most portable ways I can think of.

Answer (score 3):

Other option is TRUNCATE. Examples

```
> (truncate 2.2)
=> 2
   0.20000005

> (truncate 2.9)
=> 2
   0.9000001
```